# How to extract the entire column from a df based on a string of the column name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dfs:

Sample of df1: `s12`

```
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  ContextID   StepID  Time_Elapsed
46.6796875           7289972     12       25.443
46.6796875           7289972     12       26.443
```

Sample of df2: `step12`

```
ContextID   BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID  Time_Elapsed
7289973         46.6796875        12       26.388
7289973         46.6796875        12       27.388
```

Since the `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` is on different positions in both the dfs, I would like to know as to how can I extract the column using `df.columns.str.contains('Flow')`

I tried doing:

```
s12.columns[s12.columns.str.contains('Flow')]
```

but it just gives the following output:

> `Index(['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'], dtype='object')`

I would like the entire column to be extracted. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for get all rows and columns filtered by conditions:

```
s12.loc[:, s12.columns.str.contains('Flow')]
```

Another idea is select by columns names:

```
cols = s12.columns[s12.columns.str.contains('Flow')]
s12[cols]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael. More often than not you are my saviour here when it comes to pandas :D Appreciate it very much